# how to handle alarmclock and alarm reciever broadcasting to pause playing mediaplayer object

Tags: android, service, media-player, alarm

I am using service class to play the mp3 file using media player object on Android platform, problem is, i am not able to handle the alarm interruption.
When any previous set alarm clock reach to it's alarm time it starts to play in parallel with mp3.I want that mp3 should become paused and after alarm it again start to play,same thing should happen with snooze.

Any help would be appreciable and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I guess as Commonsware explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713484/how-to-handle-alarm-notification-in-android), receiving alarm alerts may not be a good practice but this post may be of some help to you...