# Receiving system alarm in my application Android

Tags: android, alarm

In android device if any user set alarm in default app then how can I detect or receive that alarm when its execute in my application. I don't know its possible or not if anybody knows please suggest me how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Im creating an alarm-based app right now, this is what i found earlier :

[Android get list of active alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949522/android-get-list-of-active-alarms)

[Get all alarms saved in the alarm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147179/android-get-all-alarms-saved-in-the-alarm-application)

Its a bad news.